# Zip compression

Tags: c#, compression, zip

I have:

```
public static void compress(string fileName)
    {
        using (FileStream inFile = File.OpenRead(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + subFolder + "\\" + fileName))
        {
            string newFileName = fileName.Remove(fileName.Length - 3) + "zip";
            using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + subFolder + "\\" + newFileName))
            {
                using (GZipStream Compress = new GZipStream(outFile, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    inFile.CopyTo(Compress);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The file name is for example data.txt. The compression works fine, but when I look inside the compressed file, there is file with name "data". Where is "txt" extension. File name should still have name "data.txt".

What I'm missing or doing wrong?

Regards
kazik

Comment: If u want zip then use DotNetZip http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) then append the gz extension.

Answer (score 0):

When you compress data using `GZipStream`, you’re providing it with a *stream of bytes*, not a file – the `GZipStream` instance does not know whether the stream came from a network, from memory, or from a file, and therefore cannot embed the filename into the archive.

However, all the file’s contents are preserved correctly inside the archive. You may extract them using 7zip into a new file (which is, by default, given a token name, such as `data`), rename your file back, and you would have an identical file as the one you started with.